# Problems about ProGuard when build up APK

Tags: java, android, proguard

When I build up the APK, I find out the KEYs of JSON changed when I use the Network. I just fund out that it is a problem about ProGuard.
I have added "@SerializedName" to every variables in Request/Response Folder. And added

```
-keepclassmembernames class com.mygroup.myapp.protocol.response.Responsexx {
public *;}
```

for every Resquest/Response JAVA program, which took me much time but doesn't work.

My app crashed after I get the response, the logcat says com.b.a.b.w cannot be cast to com.mygroup.myapp.b.g , and I have located the error:

```
private List<UserInfoModel> mUserList = new ArrayList<>();
private UserInfoModel UserInfo = new UserInfoModel();
if (mUserList.size()>0)
    UserInfo = mUserList.get(0); //CRASHED HERE
```

I am sure that the size of mUserList is 1, I made a toast and saw it.

Please Help Me. Much Thanks.

Moreover, the IDE I am using is Android Studio.

Comment: What about mUserList(0)? Is it null?

Comment: I made a Toast about mUserList(0), It has values.  If it is null, the LogCat can't say "cannot be cast to" problem.